Allow Player to Jump Only when on Ground Unity
I try to let the player to jump when only it is on ground but it keeps jumping even it was in the air
here is the code :
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    float moveSpeed = 5;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    float jump = 5f;
    bool isGrounded;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
 void Update()
 {
     isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.1f);

     float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveHorizontal * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

     if (isGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
     {
         rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jump, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
     }
 }



The key idea is to implement ground detection to determine if the character is on the ground when the player presses the jump key, and only if the character is on the ground can the jump operation can be performed.
Key codes are as follows, try to add them to your code:
private float groundCheckDistance;
private LayerMask whatIsGround;
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y) - groundCheckDistance));
}
void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, groundCheckDistance, whatIsGround);
}

What's more, the syntax of getting Rigidbody2D component in your code is wrong, the correct way is as follows:
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

Refer to usage of 'LayerMask' and 'Raycast':
Using Layers and Bitmask with Raycast in Unity

Have your problems been solved? Do you have any other questions? @Ahmed Hussein
